# How can I get best_in_place's respond_with_bip working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, best-in-place

I am having trouble with getting `best_in_place` fully functional. The problem is that once I edit a field, in order to be able to click on and edit that field again I need to refresh the page. I may be wrong, but I have a feeling this has something to do with `respond_with_bip` throwing an `undefined method` error. I think this has something to do with not putting the `best_in_place` assets in the right places. Currently I have the following which works to update 'constant'. But again it's throwing an error when it hits `respond_with_bip`:

**Show:**

```
<%= best_in_place constant, :description %>
```

**Update action of controller:**

```
def update
  @constant = Constant.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @constant.update_attributes(params[:constant])
      format.html { 
        flash[:success] = "Constant Updated"
        redirect_to settings_path
      }
      format.json { 
        respond_with_bip(@constant) 
      }
    else
      format.html { 
        flash[:error] = "Constant Update Failed"
        @title = "Constants"
        @constant = Constant.new
        @partial_path = "settings/constants"
        redirect_to settings_path
      }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@constant) }
    end
  end
end
```

In terms of the folder from `best_in_place`'s github page, I put the entire `lib/best_in_place` folder in my app's `app/assets` folder. The javascript files are in `app/assets/javascripts` (These are working so not worried about it). And I put the `lib/assets/best_in_place.rb` file in the `config/initializers` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This might help, https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/220. From what I was seeing there it looks like it is getting a blank and that is throwing the error your getting. If you don't need to use it you could always use:

```
redirect_to @constant
```